# Filtering query using outE() with EmbeddedMap

Tags: orientdb

I have a vertex as below.

[image]

And I also have an edge (it is an out edge of above vertex) as below.

[image]

I can query with following SQL statements.

- select from #20:6 where outE().weight in 1
- select from #28:12 where sessionStatus.keys() in "session1"

However when I combined the 2 filters above, there is no vertex out from the query.

- select from #20:6 where outE().sessionStatus.keys() in "session1"

Is there anyone guide me the correct filter I can use?

Comment: Hi, which version are you using?

Comment: it is 2.2.0, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use MATCH

```
select expand(vv) from (
    MATCH
    {
     class: GW_Score,
     as: vv,
     where: (@rid=20:6)
    }
    .outE(){
     as: ee,
     where: (sessionStatus.keys() = "session1")
    }
    RETURN vv
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
select from #20:6 where ["session1"] in outE()[0].sessionStatus.keys()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer does not work for me because there may be multiple out edges. I want to check any out-edge contains embedded map with specific key.

Comment: Can you try ```select from #20:6 where ["session1"] in outE().sessionStatus.keys()```  and let me know if it works

Comment: I think your query is not different from mine, so it still does not work. Thanks.